# Entity framework returns null only with include, despite that objects are in data base

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have strange situation. I write tests , which needs dependency injection because tested class is big. I have something like this : ( I will not paste all code because it is too big )

1. Register needed Interfaces and Classes
2. In SetUp (I Use NSubstitute) I resolve them and create new object which is my SUT object, tests are called from this service
3. In setup I have MockDbContext method when I add data to db and save it. In my case there is something like that :

```
var rounds = TestSetupHelper.GetMockedSet(DataSyncServiceTestsData.GetRounds());
            var assets = TestSetupHelper.GetMockedSet(DataSyncServiceTestsData.GetAssets());
            var roundAssets = TestSetupHelper.GetMockedSet(DataSyncServiceTestsData.GetRoundAssets());
            var reports = TestSetupHelper.GetMockedSet(DataSyncServiceTestsData.GetReportsData());
            var taskOccurrences = TestSetupHelper.GetMockedSet(DataSyncServiceTestsData.GetTaskOccurrences());
            var measurements = TestSetupHelper.GetMockedSet(DataSyncServiceTestsData.GetMeasurements());
            var included = TestSetupHelper.GetMockedSet(DataSyncServiceTestsData.GetIncludedRoundMeasurements());
            var reportsMeasurments = TestSetupHelper.GetMockedSet(DataSyncServiceTestsData.GetReportMeasurementsData());
            var assetOccurrences = TestSetupHelper.GetMockedSet(DataSyncServiceTestsData.GetAssetOccurrences());
            var areaOccurrences = TestSetupHelper.GetMockedSet(DataSyncServiceTestsData.GetAreaOccurrences());

            var powerplants = DataSyncServiceTestsData.GetPowerPlantsDataOnly();

            var parameterTypes = DataSyncServiceTestsData.GetParameterTypesDataOnly();
            var roundOccurrences = DataSyncServiceTestsData.GetRoundOccurrences();
            var signatures = DataSyncServiceTestsData.GetSignatures();

            dbContext = new AppDbContext(GetInMemoryDbContextOptions());

            dbContext.TaskOccurrences.AddRange(taskOccurrences);
            dbContext.Signatures.AddRange(signatures);
            dbContext.RoundAssets.AddRange(roundAssets);
            dbContext.AreaOccurrences.AddRange(areaOccurrences);

            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            var checker = dbContext.TaskOccurrences; // here we got 18 objects, exactly as we want to add
            var checker3 = dbContext.TaskOccurrences.Include(x => x.RoundOccurrence).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 5); //HERE we have object with id 5
```

But then, I run test and method goes to querier when I have :

```
// THIS RETURNS 18 OBJECTS as we expected
var checker1 = _queryContext.TaskOccurrences.toList();

//returns 0, despite that there are TaskOccurrences in _queryContext
            var checker2 = _queryContext.TaskOccurrences
                .Include(x => x.RoundOccurrence).ToList();
// this RETURNS NULL
            var checker3 = _queryContext.TaskOccurrences
                .Include(x => x.RoundOccurrence)
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == taskOccurrenceId);

// this RETURNS NULL 
            var entity = _queryContext.TaskOccurrences
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(x => x.RoundOccurrence)
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == taskOccurrenceId);
```

Looks like Include method resets all to null... I don't know why, I have many tests in the same way in my app , and include works fine... What can be wrong here?

Comment: Can you please a full repro? Without knowing how do you set up your data it is hard to help. But AFAIK in-memory context is not fully-blow relational db and many scenarios are not actually supported, possibly involving matching by id (i.e. you will need to use the same objects to set up correct relations). You can try using in-memory SQLLite for testing which can be more appropriate.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with ASP.NET Core so I have removed the tag. The fact that that's the type of application you're creating does not mean that the question has anything to do with that. The code you posted would be no different in any other type of application. Also, please don't post code with big wads of leading whitespace. Make the tiny effort to remove the whitespace so your code is easier for us to read. You can do it with the the Alt key while selecting in VS or use the SO editor, so there's no excuse.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that `FirstOrDefault` (the first line in the second code sample) returns 18 occurrences. What am I missing?

Comment: How do you generate `DataSyncServiceTestsData.GetRoundOccurrences()`? Do they have corresponding foreign keys that match in `TaskOccurrences`?

Comment: What is _queryContext in relation to the earlier dbContext?? You have one block of code that is creating and inserting data into a DbContext instance, but then in the non-working code you are referring to a different DbContext instance.

Comment: @StevePy I have DbContext : ICommandContext : IQueryContext, so if I will add data to dbContext it will be also in _queryContext, the data is inside,

Comment: This issue is known in EFCore github issues, https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/9470, probably there is a problem with inMemory db relations, because include takes only innerJoin

Comment: I also figure out that Include from first screen comes from System.Data.Entity, but the second one from EFCore package. The difference under them probably caused the issue

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a possible migration/mix issue between EF (.Net Framework) and EF Core.  There are also some differences in behaviour between EF against different DB engine providers, including in-memory.  In-memory isn't 100% guaranteed to be able to substitute a database to swap out a connection for things like unit testing. For that I recommend the repository pattern and mocking the repository rather than substituting the DB or trying to mock a DbContext.